# Several Images in UV and Shading

Tags: uv, shaders

I'm new to Blender.

I'm trying to insert several images on one object face. The problem is that the background and the image on top are moving as one. I can't adjust the size, rotation ect. separately.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 Mapping nodes in order to control them independently:

[image]